# For Loop Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to figure out the best way to loop a given number of times within a Django template from an integer field

For example, if I have a model:

```py
models.py

class Rating(models.Model):
   checked = models.IntegerField(default='0')
   unchecked = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

And I have a record where `checked = 5`, in the template how can I do the following:

```py
{% for i in checked %}
<div>some repeatable content here </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Since `checked` is an integer, it is a non-iterable and it cannot be used in the for-loop. Is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `range(checked)` to template and then iterate. Or you can create property:

```
@property
def checked_range(self):
    return range(self.checked)
```

and use it in template like so:

```
{% for i in rating.checked_range %}
    <div>some repeatable content here </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Just for other who may read: the `@property` goes on your model.